# Tyring to figure out generic method signatures in Collections

Tags: java, methods, collections, signature

What does the first `<T>` mean in the generic method signature:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

And where can I find information that goes in details about generic method signatures?

Comment: I don't see any generic method signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is a [type parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html) to your method.  This means that you can now provide a generic type to your sort method.

In general, you would call the method in this manner:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
Comparator<Integer> intComparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer left, Integer right) {
        return left.compareTo(right);
    }
}

sort(intList, intComparator);
```

The method call is bound to the generic argument (which is inferred as `Integer`).  But it doesn't have to be `Integer` - it could be `String`, `Float`, or some custom object you come up with.

Comment: Should nt the second <T> in the method argument (List<T>) imply the same? Why a <T> before "void", considering that the method does not return anything?

Comment: No, it's not quite the same.  `<T>` doesn't imply a return type; it only indicates that one is allowing a generic type to be passed in. That's also the *only* way you'll get a generic type of anything into that method (unless the class is also declared generic of type `T`).  If you don't provide `T` as a type parameter, Java will believe that an object called `T` exists, and will try to find it - only to (hopefully!) fail at compilation time.  Or worse - if you left them as raw types, you would have to do type casts since you'd only have `Object` to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a static [sorting method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) in class Collections that you are looking at. Sorts with comparisons made by your custom comparator.